# Finding perpendicular vector with a given formula

Tags: linear-algebra

Question:  with v=(1,1) and w=(1,5), find the number c so that w-cv is perpendicular to v.

Ans: to be perpendicular dot|(w-cv).v| = 0
                        =(1,5)-c(1,1).(1,1)=0
                        =(1,5)-2c=0      So far, all is understood. The next..?
                        =6-2c=0 and therefore c= 3.
Where did the 6 come from?
      Is it the 1+5 of the w?
      Or is it the w.w ?
Appreciate any help. Self teaching Linear Algebra!

Comment: $(1,5)-2c$ appears to be a vector minus a scalar.  How can this be correct?

Comment: I think you meant $[(1,5)-c(1,1)]\cdot(1,1)=(1-c,5-c)\cdot(1,1)=(1-c)+(5-c)=6-2c=0$

Answer (score 1):

$w.v-cv.v=0$ and $6$ is $w.v$.

[$(w-cv).v=w.v -cv.v$].

Comment: Again, Thank you, Mr. Murthy. I am a retired Prof of Medicine and Nephrology. Trying to form math base, so I can move on to Astrophysics. At 73 years of age, I notice things in math that should be obvious, do not appear to be all that obvious...until someone points it out. I am sure I will overcome it. Till then I can use all your (and others willing) help.
Thank you again.